# c# webform Code won't update my Access database

Tags: c#, oledb

Hi guys this is code on a page titled Forgot password.aspx
I need the user to provide their email, in order for them to reset their password.

The problem is the program does run, but the record in the database is not updated, and the user is just redirected to the sign in page

Am I doing something wrong?
please help!

```
protected void save_Password_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
    connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                                    Data Source=C:\Users\Student\Documents\websiteDatabase.accdb";


    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT password FROM userInformation where emailAddress = '" + p_Email.Text + "'", connect);


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();


    adapter.Fill(dt);



    if ( dt.Rows.Count.ToString() == "1")
    {

        if(tb_newPassword.Text == tb_Confirm.Text)
        {

            //Opens the connection
            connect.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = connect.CreateCommand();   


            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE userInformation SET password ='" + tb_Confirm.Text + "' WHERE emailAddress = '" + p_Email.Text  + "'";


            MessageBox.Show("Password changed successfully!");


            Response.Redirect("Sign In Page.aspx");

            //Closes the connection
            connect.Close();
        }
        else
        {

            lbl.Text = "Passwords do not match!";

        }
    }
    else
    {

        lbl.Text=" Change unsuccessful, please try again";

    }

}
```

Comment: Always parametrized queries. Always check the results from your actions. Don't output confirmation messages just because you have performed some action.

Comment: Also, do NOT keep passwords in plain text in DB (unless this snippet is just simplified for clarity sake)

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute your command:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE userInformation SET password ='" + tb_Confirm.Text + "' WHERE emailAddress = '" + p_Email.Text  + "'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show("Password changed successfully!");
```

Comment: You are not taking any result from the ExecuteNonQuery() and right after it you confirm that something has happened... The method returns int. Check if there are actually affected rows.

Comment: @Gnqz you are probably right, but this seems out of scope of this question

Comment: @slawekwin I added the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() but it returns an error

Comment: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Source Error: 


Line 82:                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: well, as the exception message states, there is an error in your UPDATE query. As the string seems ok, I would guess that you misspelled table or column names or values you entered have to be escaped before posting in the sql (always a good idea regardless, see a Gnqz's comment to the question). Also, maybe there is inner exception specifying what syntax error was this?

Comment: i can't seem to find the problem, all column names and the table names are correct, I double checked

Comment: what happens when you post the same query in ssms?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```
            string email = p_Email.Text;
            string password  = tb_Confirm.Text

            try
                {
                        connect.Open();
                        OleDbCommand cmd = connect.CreateCommand();

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE userInformation SET [password]= @password WHERE emailAddress= @email";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tb_Confirm.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", p_Email.Text);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connect.Close();
                }
```